# Hibernate Loading not loading the whole tree

Tags: java, database, hibernate, tree

I am trying to make hibernate load my whole tree with no success.

I have a schema like this
A Category can have many attribute and an attribute can have many options

```
Category
    --->Attribute1
        --->AttributeOption1
        --->AttributeOption3
    --->Attribute2
        --->AttributeOption1
        --->AttributeOption1
```

but when I am using hibernate, it is not loading the whole tree:
my mapping file are:

```
Attribute Mapping FIle:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Dec 16, 2010 5:25:09 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.Beta1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.BiddingSystem.Models.Attribute" table="ATTRIBUTE">
        <id name="AttributeId" type="long">
            <column name="ATTRIBUTEID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="AttributeName" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="ATTRIBUTENAME" />
        </property>
        <set name="Options" table="ATTRIBUTEOPTION" inverse="false"  cascade="all" lazy="true">
            <key>
                <column name="ATTRIBUTEID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.BiddingSystem.Models.AttributeOption" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

Attribute Option Mapping File:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Dec 16, 2010 5:25:09 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.Beta1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.BiddingSystem.Models.AttributeOption" table="ATTRIBUTEOPTION">
        <id name="AttributeOptionId" type="long">
            <column name="ATTRIBUTEOPTIONID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="Option" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="OPTION" />
        </property>
        <property name="SQLValue" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="SQLVALUE" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

Category Mapping File:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Dec 16, 2010 8:37:02 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.Beta1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.BiddingSystem.Models.Category" table="CATEGORY">
        <id name="CategoryId" type="long">
            <column name="CATEGORYID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="CategoryName" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="CATEGORYNAME" />
        </property>

        <many-to-one name="ParentCategory" class="com.BiddingSystem.Models.Category">
            <column name="PARENT_CATEGORY_ID" />
        </many-to-one>

        <set name="SubCategory" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true">
            <key>
                <column name="PARENT_CATEGORY_ID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.BiddingSystem.Models.Category" />
        </set>

        <set name="AllAttributes" table="ATTRIBUTE"  inverse="false" lazy="true"  cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="CATEGORYID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.BiddingSystem.Models.Attribute" />
        </set>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The function that loads the parent category are:

```
public List <Category> getCategory(long CategoryId) 
    {
        Session session = gileadHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        List <Category> AllCategory= new LinkedList<Category> ();
        String SQL="from Category where parent_category_id is NULL";
        Query query = session.createQuery(SQL);
        return query.list();
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'it is not loading the whole tree'? -- Not every Category, not the whole tree by one query (lazyloading), or loading subcategories are not loaded if they are accessed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make all your associations lazy=false; by default the lazy = true

Comment: In the mapping, SubCategory is explicite layz loaded: 'name="SubCategory" lazy="true"'

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is an other mistake:

```
String SQL="from Category where parent_category_id is NULL";
Query query = session.createQuery(SQL);
```

`org.hibernate.Session.createQuery(String queryString)` requires a HQL Query String, but not a SQL query! And `from Category where parent_category_id is NULL` seems to be a SQL query, because `parent_category_id` is a column name but not a property / field name.